# Is it possible to provide access to customer to download data that posted in chatter

Tags: community, chatter, permissions

Is it possible to provide access to end customer to download data that posted in the chatter or in communities?

Comment: What type of data - files? post content?

Comment: @DaveHumm Dashboard, Image or Any attachment types.

Comment: Which community user licence is it? Customer Community or Customer Community Plus?

Comment: @DaveHumm Customer Community

Comment: Customer Community licence does not have access to Dashboards or Reports, Files, Attachments and Documents can be made available to them.

Comment: @DaveHumm So in Customer community Plus license will allow end user customer to access and download files attachments etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for users on the Customer Community licence to access Files and Libraries in Salesforce.

In the Naplili template there is a standard component accessible from the Community Builder that lets you surface files from Chatter to community users.A simple way of doing this is to create Chatter groups in the community and add the relevant community users and files to them.

In the Napili template I have done this with a navigation menu item for the Group object then used this to add groups and invite community members to them where I can add the files, see images. These screenshots have been done using a standard customer community licence user.

[image: Groups in community]

[image: Files in community]

It is not possible to share Dashboards or Reports with users on the Customer Community licence. A workaround can be to build a Visualforce page that displays the relevant fields and has access granted to the relevant user profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want access to require a user to be logged in, or do you want a file to be publicly accessible?

If you want a publicly accessible file, our [Share via Link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_sharing_via_link.htm&type=0) feature may be what you want.  If you want to require authenticated access, then the file should be accessible if it is posted on a feed which is accessible to the community user.